# I can't get this script to change the CSS of a IMG on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me why this script is not working. I got it from another answer on this site. And tried to change it to fit my needs and it is not working.
I'm trying to change the CSS from #tsclogo to .tsclogo then back again if you scroll up.
*Note: I removed the image src and href links*

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
var nav = document.getElementById("loot").getElementsByTagName("img")
[0].src="Some IMAGE";
if ( window.pageYOffset > 100 ) {
    nav.classList.add("tsclogox");
} else {
    nav.classList.remove("tsclogox");
}
}
</script>
```

**html**

```
<div id="loot" class="heady-logo">   
<a href="some link" accesskey="1"><img id="tsclogo" src="some img" alt="IPS Community Suite"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tsclogox {
height: 40px !important;
position: fixed;
top: -6px;
}

#tsclogo {
max-width: 100%;
height: 59px;
-webkit-transition: height 1s;
-ms-transition: height 1s;
transition: height 1s;
position: relative;
z-index: 9000;
```

}

Comment: your code does this `var nav = document.getElementById("loot").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="Some IMAGE";` - see how that's one line because you didn't use `;` - in other words, `nav` will be the string `"Some Image"` - a quick look at the **developer** tools console would've shown some errors regarding `classList` or morelikely undefined not having a method called add/remove

Comment: so I'm missing a ;  ?

Comment: a little more than that would be required ... `var nav = document.getElementById("loot").getElementsByTagName("img")[‌​0]; nav.src="Some IMAGE";`

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs minor corrections (as already mentioned in the comments). But I think for what you are trying to achieve, you also need to change your CSS to add `!important` to your positioning for `.tsclogox`. This is because your CSS for `#tsclogo` has a `position: relative`, and `#tsclogo` is more specific than `.tsclogox`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zcx1sL7/1/) which shows what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This help you:
http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/2.0/Image
I hope is useful. good luck and try to search more on google instead get negative on you questions